Pros and cons of Curvenote and Overleaf
I am planning to publish my first math papers in a way that meets professional's criteria.
Especially in the initial phase I would like to be aided with automated generation of document layout, embedding graphics and pictures and also referencing of equations and bibliography.
Currently I'm torn between curvenote and overleaf as tools that offer what I need.
Question:
what are the pros and cons of overleaf and curvenote with respect to enabling LaTeX novices to master professional math-publications?

welcome! I'm not sure this is a good question for this site. curvenote seems largely off-topic. (it can export to latex, I think, but so can other tools.) it's also like asking for the pros and cons of, say, pandoc versus kile. they're different tools with different purposes. it's not clear how to usefully compare them in a general way. if you don't want to deal with the coding, possibly curvenote is better. but if you want to learn latex, overleaf would be much better.

Note that the "professional's criteria" are mainly concerned with the content of the papers and less so with the layout of the document or formatting of the equations or bibliography. If, based on the content, your paper is accepted after peer review in a journal, then the journal will take care of the professional appearance for you. That said, the instructions for authors when submitting a manuscript for peer review often supply a LaTeX style/class/template, to use that you need LaTeX (for example via Overleaf) and not some other typesetting system like Curvenote.
